# patent Infringment on my product

Tags: design, infringment

1]: https://www.google.com/patents/USD763495

I hired a company to design and bring my product to the market. They drug there feet and took so long other similar inventions came into play. What can I do since it's been such a long time , to be sure they did not purposely stall the process or give the details to others? Thanks

Comment: This is a little hard to respond to since we don't know what you consider your patentable idea. The cited patent is a design patent which only covers the ornamental design and not the function.

Comment: Further to @EricShain's comment, the patent-related aspect of this is a little unclear, other than the title. The underlying question about how you can know whether you can trust a (non-patent-related) contractor is an interesting one, but may not be a good fit for this site.